Is there a way to get mail body in Outlook with Office.js
I am trying to create a mobile add-in with Office.js and I am using OnNewMessageCompose event.
10 second after event launched, I am trying to get body with the code below but it doesnt work.
async function getEmailBody() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
          Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(Office.CoercionType.Html, function (asyncResult) {
              if (asyncResult.status == "failed") {
                    resolve(null);
                  } else {
                    resolve(asyncResult.value);
                  }
                });
    });

  }, 10 * 1000);
}

async function newMessageCompose(event) {
  const body = await getEmailBody()
console.log(body)
  event.completed();
}

It immidiatly goes error and mail body has value its not empty. It Work with Web and Desktop application but not with mobile



Office js doesn't support update bodt in mobilebu you can change body with Graph api
